# How to open ContextMenu after clicking on IconButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to open ContextMenu after left-clicking on IconButton...
I have this code for my button:

```
<Controls:IconButton Visibility="{Binding IsFunctionalityVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="&#xf039;" ToolTip="Více možností">
              <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                  <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="OpenContextMenu">
                  </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Controls:IconButton>
```

The problem is, I cant use ActionMessage like this, because I don't know how to create function "OpenContextMenu" in ViewModel.

Can I use for example Pop-up instead of ContextMenu (add Pop-up to my IconButton style somehow?)?

EDIT:
This is my style for IconButton:

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundColor}" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Border  BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFont}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Border>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="ContentControl" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundActiveColor}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="ContentControl" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundActiveColor}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>  
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

EDIT no.2: I want ContextMenu like this after clicking that blue IconButton on last pic (not after right click)

[image: I want ContextMenu like this]

[image: After clicking this IconButton]

Comment: Are you sure you want a context menu? It sounds like you have a regular menu with one top-item. No?

Comment: It was told to me in my job. They want a context menu. I am new in xaml, how can I add there that regular menu? I will add screenshots of context menu I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the MouseDown event of an Image like this:

```
<Controls:IconButton ... MouseDown="Image_MouseDown">
<Controls:IconButton.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem .../>
        <MenuItem .../>
    </ContextMenu>
</Controls:IconButton.ContextMenu>
</Controls:IconButton>
```

And then show the ContextMenu in the EventHandler in code behind:

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
       e.Handled = true;
       Image image = sender as Image;
       ContextMenu contextMenu = image.ContextMenu;
       contextMenu.PlacementTarget = image;
       contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to do this by using more complex way... I have to use DependencyProperty and so on, because of the template